# Subspace of a normal space

Tags: general-topology

I had to show that a closed subspace of a normal space is normal.

To show that, I let $X$ be a normal space, and $C$ be a closed subset of $X$.

And take disjoint $A$ and $B$ such that closed subsets of $C$.

Since $A$, $B$ are also closed in $X$, by normality of $X$, there exist disjoint open $U$, $V$ s.t. contain $A$, $B$ respectively.

Then $U\cap C$, $V\cap C$ are open in $C$, disjoint and contain $A$, $B$ respectively.

Hence $C$ is also normal.

In this proccess, I don't know why $C$ has to be closed. I can't find error in this proof either.

What am I missing here?

Comment: @DavidMitra Since $C$ is closed, they are also closed in $X$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Silly me, thanks.

Comment: And that, janna, is the point. If $C$ is not closed, then closed subsets of $C$ generally aren't closed in $X$.

Comment: Thanks. :) helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used it when you stated that $A,B$ are also closed in $X$. By assumption they are closed  in $C$, so there are closed $F,G$ closed in $X$, such that $A = F \cap C$ and $B = G \cap C$. But then $A$ and $B$ are indeed closed in $X$ as the intersection of two closed sets of $X$.

In short, closed in closed is closed. (And the same holds for open in open, same proof.)